# If using previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, if-statement

How can I create an if statement based on what the previous activity was? I get to the page from an intent but it is not always from the same activity. I want some code to execute ONLY when the previous activity was a given one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an intent parameter from your 'previous' activity. You can check for it's existence in the new activity and act accordingly if it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Define an `EXTRA_` to control whether such code should execute or not, and make the calling activities specify that value in the `Intent` if they want the code to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

in the activity that starts the new activity, add flags to your Intent

```
Intent nextActivity = new Intent(thisActivity.this, nextActivity.class
nextActivity.putExtra("key", "value");
startActivity(intent);
```

in the next activity, you check for the "extra"s that came with your intent, during `onCreate()`

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras!=null) 
{
     if(extras.getString("key").contentEquals("value")
     {
       //then you know what activity you just came from
     }
 }
```